Get consolidated logs for AWS Lambda@Edge function at one region in Cloudfront
I have a Lambda@Edge function that is deployed in multiple AWS regions and its logs are currently being pushed to CloudWatch log groups in their respective AWS regions. I want to consolidate these logs into a single CloudWatch Logs log group in one AWS region (e.g., us-east-1) for easier access and centralized log management.
Could someone please provide a detailed method or best practices to achieve this? Specifically, I am looking for a way to automatically route or push all logs from the various regional CloudWatch log groups to a centralized CloudWatch Logs log group in the chosen region (us-east-1).
I tried to find an option/setting in AWS console to set this but couldn't.
